# Postgres 11 join tables using jsonb values

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have two tables:

```
create table device_group_v2
(
    id        uuid not null primary key,
    name      varchar(255),
    filter    jsonb
);
```

with one entry:

```
+--------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
|                  id                  |    name    |               filter                |
+--------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
| 92f9ac68-7baa-4322-8eb1-e6b9e83dd2ef | Devices-UK | [{"key": "country", "value": "uk"}] |
+--------------------------------------+------------+-------------------------------------+
```

and

```
create table device_entity
(
    id       uuid not null primary key,
    name     varchar(255),
    metadata jsonb
);
```

With one entry:

```
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
|                  id                  |        name         |     metadata      |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
| 75cf91d0-01b7-42e0-9791-86def0dc4b7b | Device 7 - Metadata | {"country": "uk"} |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------+
```

Is it possible to join both tables, so I get all devices having key/value as defined in the filter in **TestGroup**?

In the given example it's this query, but I need to fill 'country' and 'uk' dynamically from the "filter" column in the device_group_v2 table.

```
SELECT * from device_entity where (metadata ->> 'country') = 'uk';
```

If there are multiple key-value entries, all should be combined with an OR. I need to fetch any of these elements that match the given filters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a [number of different ways](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) to do this, but the easiest might be:

- Join the tables on the condition that `NOT EXISTS` anything in a subquery that:
- You break-out the `filter` array using `jsonb_to_recordset`
- Then `EXCEPT` from it the break-out of the `metadata` object using `jsonb_each_text`

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM device_group_v2 g
JOIN device_entity e
  ON NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT f."key", f.value
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset(g.filter) AS f("key" text, value text)

    EXCEPT

    SELECT md."key", md.value
    FROM jsonb_each_text(e.metadata) md
    )
WHERE g.name = 'Devices-UK';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/vS6tlV9_)

This gets you the result if you want to `AND` all the filters. If you want to `OR` them, change the `NOT EXISTS` to `EXISTS` and `EXCEPT` to `INTERSECT`

```sql
SELECT e.*
FROM device_group_v2 g
JOIN device_entity e
  ON EXISTS (
    SELECT f."key", f.value
    FROM jsonb_to_recordset(g.filter) AS f("key" text, value text)

    INTERSECT

    SELECT md."key", md.value
    FROM jsonb_each_text(e.metadata) md
    )
WHERE g.name = 'Devices-UK';
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/EpsbkF0W)